# How to configure Devise+Cancan correctly for guest users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

In a Rails 3.2 app I'm using Devise + CanCan. The app previously restricted access to only logged in users. I'm in the process of adding a Guest user/ability that will be able to read certain sections of the site.

I'm having trouble understanding the "correct" way to set this up, specifically what combination of `before_filter :authenticate!` and `load_and_authorize_resource` is needed in controllers.

While working on this I've stripped the ability class to a minimum.

```
#Ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user_or_admin)
    user_or_admin ||= User.new

    can :manage, :all
  end
end
```

In a model-less/ static page Home controller

```
#home_controller.rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  def index
    ...some stuff
  end
end
```

and

```
#application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :authenticate!
  ...more stuff
end
```

With this set up, un-logged-in users are redirected to Devise sign in page.

If I remove `before_filter :authenticate!` from the application controller I get an error `uninitialized constant Home` from `activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb`

If I remove `load_and_authorize_resource` from the home controller, this error goes away.

This is ok with my simplified testing Ability class, but as I start adding roles and abilities back in I will need to have CanCan handling the Home controller, i.e., will need `load_and_authorize_resource` to be called.

Can anyone help me understand why this error occurs when `before_filter :authenticate!` is removed, and point me towards any info that explain the "correct" way to set up Devise+Cancan for guest users. The info I've found thus far only explains how to set up the Ability class, not how to configure Devise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there is no resource to authorize. Therefore, you need only call `authorize_resource` not `load_and_authorize_resource`. See [authorizing controller actions](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-Controller-Actions) in the cancan documentation for further information.

Update: You must also specify the class as false: `authorize_resource class: false`.

Then your home controller will look like this:

```
class HomeController < ActionController::Base
  authorize_resource class: false

  def show
    # automatically calls authorize!(:show, :home)
  end
end
```

This information is in the [Non-RESTful controllers section](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Non-RESTful-Controllers). Sorry about that.

Comment: thanks @max, this makes sense and I've learned something new. But, when I call only `authorize_resource` from the home controller, I still receive the `initialized constant` error. Do you know where else I could look for the cause of this problem.